# why Ax=0 forms a vector space but Ax=b does not?

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this statement and am wondering why this is so:

(i)  The solutions to Ax=0 form a vector space.  True.  This is the nullspace, Nul(A).

(ii)  The solutions to Ax=b form a vector space.  False, unless b= 0

Is there kind of proof to these statements? Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: (ii) is easy to show because the zero vector is not in the solution space.  For (i), you just have to show that sums and scalar multiples of solutions are also solutions, which is easy as well.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a vector space? Is 0 vector a solution to (ii)

Comment: Lookup “vector subspace test” you can do the proof

Comment: It forms an affine space.

Answer (score 4):

If $\{\mathbf x : A\mathbf x = \mathbf b\}$ is a vector space, then it should be closed under addition:

If $\mathbf x,\mathbf y$ are solutions of the equation $A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$ and $A\mathbf y = \mathbf b$, then $A(\mathbf x + \mathbf y) = A\mathbf x + A\mathbf y = 2\mathbf b \ne \mathbf b$ unless $\mathbf b = \mathbf 0$. Hence the collection $\{\mathbf x : A\mathbf x = \mathbf b\}$ is a vector space if and only if $\mathbf b = \mathbf 0$.

Comment: In particular if $Ax=b\ne 0$ then $A(x+x)=2b\ne b$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Suppose that $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ both satisfies $$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$$ Is it also true that $\mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\right)=\mathbf{b}$? What must $\mathbf{b}$ be (no pun intended) for this to be true?